# Change IP address Ubuntu Server

Tags: server

Is there a way to change the IP address of a Ubuntu Server that boots straight to playing videos. We have one set up as a Caesy Server and I cannot change the IP. I have tried booting to rescue disk and changing then but after reboot it always changes back to the original.

Comment: How exactly have you tried? Where did you enter the new IP address?

Comment: Often you can set a static IP on your router. Otherwise configure Ubuntu to use a static IP https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the boot disk, then edit `/etc/network/interfaces` (just make sure it's not the boot disk's `etc/network/interfaces` you're trying to edit) and change the IP there. Change it in `/etc/hosts` as well (if it's there). It will use the `etc/network/interfaces` IP address when it boots up, regardless of what you used ifconfig to change it to before rebooting.

Comment: What is in `/etc/hosts` that he needs to change?

Comment: @chili555 some people have a direct IP->hostname mapping for the current server as well in `/etc/hosts`. Never figured out why they add it, but...

Comment: @muru some system software that automatically detects the FQDN looks in /etc/hosts to see if such an entry is there.  For example, if it looks in /etc/hostname and does not find the full FQDN it will look for an entry in /etc/hosts that refers to the relevant network interface.  Whether this is a good idea I can't comment.

Comment: @thomasrutter thing is, the relevant network interface doesn't have to be the ethernet one, you can simply tack on `127.0.1.1` or even on to `127.0.0.1` or `:::1` itself (in addition to the usual  `localhost` entry).

Comment: eg, [hostname -f](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/hostname.1.html) command does this.